# MySQL Simple COUNT taking very long time

Tags: mysql, performance, count

I have a database with over 870.000 rows. Each time I receive a request I have to executed an COUNT to check wether a row exists or not. These COUNT requests take up to 180 seconds before they are executed. Which is pretty long.

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(0) AS aantal FROM milk_quotes WHERE shopId = '438' AND quoteId = '17424765'
```

EXPLAIN EXTENDED shows:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  milk_quotes ref shopId  shopId  4   const   87648   100.00  Using where
```

And the table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `milk_quotes ` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shopId` mediumint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quoteId` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerId` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerIP` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `recoveryHash` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT 'nl',
  `channel` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `productsCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isPaid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `isNotified` enum('0','1') CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT '0',
  `paymentId` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `paymentCountry` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceIncl` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `shopUpdatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `recalculatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `shopCreatedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstReminder` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondReminder` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thirdReminder` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `skipQuote` enum('1','0') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `isPaid` (`isPaid`),
  KEY `shopId` (`shopId`),
  KEY `firstReminder` (`firstReminder`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=930952 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Inno DB variables:

```
have_innodb YES
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 1048576
innodb_autoextend_increment 8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_size 8388608
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_concurrency_tickets  500
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_io_threads  4
innodb_file_per_table   OFF
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method 
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  1048576
innodb_log_file_size    5242880
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   ./
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  90
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_open_files   300
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_stats_on_metadata    ON
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_spin_loops  20
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   8
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm ON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query can only use one index per table in each query; thus, if you are looking up several fields in a single query, you need to have an index that covers all of them. In your query, `shopId` index is used, but within that `quoteId` is scanned sequentially, which is Not Great (I assume there's a bunch of `quoteId` rows per each shop, yes?). Try changing the `shopId` index in your schema to

```
KEY `shopAndQuoteIds` (`shopId`, `quoteId`),
```

(if you want to do it on an existing table, I believe `ALTER TABLE aantal DROP INDEX shopId` followed by `ALTER TABLE aantal ADD KEY shopAndQuoteIds (shopId, quoteId)` should do it. Do back up your DB before doing this! Or, you could dump the table, alter the schema to the above, then reimport it back.)

Note that any prefix of a key can be used; so `(shopId, quoteId)` index can be used for a `shopId` query and a `shopId` + `quoteId` query, but not for a `quoteId` query. The fact that it can still be used for a plain `shopId` query means you lose nothing by creating this new index and dropping the old `shopId` one.

Comment: Hi Amadan, thanks! Is this all i can tweak or are there more options? (Index is being created as wee speak).

Comment: No idea. This is an obvious change that should speed things up considerably; I can't think of much else. (I am not a conf wizard, and my databases usually run well enough on default settings)

Comment: Well, only one way to tell: profile the query again after the index is rebuilt :)

Comment: Tremendous improvement! Works great.